# Jump to matching brace in Xcode

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In Xcode, if the cursor is on one brace (or bracket or parenthesis) of a matched pair, what keyboard shortcut will jump to the matching brace? Or how can I create such a shortcut?

An example of the feature I'm after is the "goto brace" [shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio) in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a Balance Delimiters menu command. So simply assign it any keyboard shortcut you prefer (all commands have customizable key bindings). You can also double-click the first delimiter to perform the same action.

Comment: Double click is simple.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and found a way to do this quickly, but it's not a keyboard shortcut (you have to use the mouse):

1. Double-click on the brace. This selects the brace, the closing brace, and everything in between.
2. Type right-arrow. This de-selects everything and places the cursor after the closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution is to use code folding. For example, to jump from the opening brace to the closing brace:

1. Put the cursor just after the opening brace.
2. Fold with <kbd>⌥⌘←</kbd>.
3. Arrow the cursor right to just before the closing brace.
4. Unfold with <kbd>⌥⌘←</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Since Xcode now has Vim mode you can use that and just hit `%`.

(Adding this answer for completeness - I understand it kind of amounts to "just use Vim".)